# looping through an AJAX get request data to see 'checked' inputs with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, input, razor

I have this Ajax request that gets some inputs data but i want to see them checked when i open the modal. I tried with jquery to assign at least one of multiple inputs but it doesn't work.

```
@foreach (var group in groupsSelect)
   {
    <input type="checkbox" class="group form-check-input" name="group" id="group-@group.Value" value="@group.Value" />
    <label for="group-@group.Value" class="col-md-2 control-label inline">@group.Text</label>
    <br /><br />
    groupsIndex++;
   }
```

and to check them i tried with:

```
 var objSelect = $("#editGroupsContainer input[class=group]");
        setSelectedValue(objSelect, group);

function setSelectedValue(selectObj, valueToSet) {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectObj.length; i++) {
        $(selectObj).attr("checkbox", ":checked")
    }
}
```

but the log only shows all the inputs in the **forEach** loop, not the checked ones that i got from the request

Answer (score 0):

> but the log only shows all the inputs in the forEach loop, not the checked ones that i got from the request

If you want to get the checked checkboxes in the element which id is `editGroupsContainer`.You can try to use:

```
var selectedObjs=$("#editGroupsContainer input[class=group]:checked");
```